# NameError: name 'Series' is not defined while using Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am new to python. I am using anaconda and trying to write some python code in it. I have written 2 lines of code in which I am trying to create a Series data from a dictonary[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ApurvG there is no function called Series in native python.
If your question is about pandas series you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dictionary={'apurb':400}
series = pd.Series(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter:-

salary = {'John': 5000, 'Rob': 6000, 'Wills':7500, 'Ashu': 5500}

salary

### se3 = Series(salary)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13716/1803553183.py in 
----> 1 se3 = Series(salary)

NameError: name 'Series' is not defined

import pandas as pd

se4 = pd.Series(salary)

se4
John     5000
Rob      6000
Wills    7500
Ashu     5500
dtype: int64

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).